# JQuery. text() does not seem to work in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have the following XML as a string:

```
<battery_content>
    <last_update>2012-15-09-22-40</last_update>
    <total_downloads>234</total_downloads>
    ......
</battery_content>
```

I get the XML from an Ajax request and I store it in `sXMLData`. I do a quick `window.alert(sXMLData)` and everything's fine.

When I run the next code in IE8, it won't seem to work. Chrome and Firefox work.

```
window.alert("last_update" + $(sXMLData).find("last_update").text());
```

I can't seem to figure out why. Does this method not work with IE8? If so, how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Parsing the XML properly with [`$.parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) first should solve the problem.

Comment: Please write your comment as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to handle "XML as a dumb string" is to pass it through [`$.parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) first:

```
 window.alert(
     "last_update" + $($.parseXML(sXMLData)).find("last_update").text());
```

However, you wouldn't need to do this manually if

- *either* the server returns an XML `Content-Type`,
- *or* the AJAX request you fetch the XML with uses the [`dataType`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) AJAX option to specify that the response should be treated as XML

If the server is under your control, fix it to return the proper content type. If not, use the alternative solution. I recommend parsing the XML manually only if you are getting the string from third-party code that you have good reason to not want to touch.

Comment: **1.** I'd like to point out that AJAX at its core does not differentiate between XML or indeed any other format. It's jQuery that does the job. Yet another reason why AJAX' naming is seriously flawed. **2.** I don't see any reason why one would want to parse the XML from an AJAX call manually. I would recommend using the dataType option correctly at all times.

Comment: @Christian: When saying "AJAX", I mean `$.ajax` or any other jQuery function that's implemented in terms of that.